# How to stop awaiting ainput funcion from another coroutine/task

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I want to stop awaiting `ainput` function at 6th iteration of `for` loop

```
import asyncio
from aioconsole import ainput

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.read = True

    async def read_from_concole(self):

        while self.read:
            command = await ainput('$>')

            if command == 'exit':
                self.read = False
            
            if command == 'greet':
                print('greetings :J')


    async def count(self):

        console_task = asyncio.create_task(self.read_from_concole())

        for c in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(.5)
            print(f'number: {c}')

            if c == 5: # 6th iteration
                # What shoud I do here?
                # Following code doesn't meet my expectations
                self.read = False
                console_task.cancel()
        
        await console_task


    # async def run_both(self):
    #     await asyncio.gather(
    #                         self.read_from_concole(),
    #                         self.count()
    #                         )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o1 = Test()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(o1.count())
```

Of course, this code is simplified, but covers the idea: **write a program where one coroutine can cancel another which is awaiting something** (in this example `ainput`.
`asyncio.Task.cancel()` is not the solution because it won't make coroutine stop awaiting (so I need put arbitrary character into console and press enter, this is not what I want).

I don't even know whether my approach makes sense, I'm a fresh asyncio user, for now, I know only the basics. In my real project, the situation is very similar. I have a GUI application and a console window. By clicking 'X' button I want to close window and terminate `ainput` (which read commands from the console) to completely finish the program (the console part is working on a different thread, and because of that I can't close my program completely - this thread will run until `ainput` receive some input from a user).

Comment: What are you trying to stop, the loop (`break`) or `count` (`return`)?

Comment: Your program works as I'd expect it to. You correctly cancel the `read_from_console()` task, but you don't break out of the loop, which is why further iterations are printed. Following the loop, awaiting the cancelled task correctly raises `CancelledError`. Maybe you're missing a `break` after `console_task.cancel`? Also note that you shouldn't need to check `self.read`, cancellation will raise an exception at the point of `await ainput()`, so that `while` loop will be automatically abandoned.

Comment: @user4815162342 adding `break` just prevent printing out remaining numbers in the iterable, I just forgot to add that but this is not the real issue. What is the real issue then? I think the `CancelledError` you mentioned is raised only after I pass some input into the console because `ainput` awaits it. I don't want to my program need my engagement such as that. Actually, in this example, the program should entirely exit the event loop after reaching the 6th iteration in `for` loop.

Comment: @dirn by calling `count` method I want to stop the `read_from_console` method inside which I'm constantly awaiting `ainput` function.

Comment: That's not the behavior I see - I don't need to press enter before observing the `CancelledError`. What OS are you running it on?

Comment: Windows. [Here is what I see after launching](https://imgur.com/a/kZoqsRs)